# What is a tertile average of a group?

Tags: mean, biostatistics

I came across a paper , where they have taken tertile average of a hormone level in a group. I am wondering what difference does calculating tertile average make?

Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

What they mean is that groups were divided into thirds based on some continuous measure (here hormones). And then the average of that measure was taken between groups.

Example R code:

```
x <- rnorm(100)
tapply(x, cut(x, quantile(x, 0:3/3)), mean)
```

I advocate doing this for any general analysis. It can be useful when splitting groups in multimodal data where the average marker value between groups may not be easy to predict or guess.

A common approach to using tertiles in analyses to adjust for them as factors. This allows your model to fit non-linear effects if there's a possible quadratic trend. One may also use quartiles, deciles, etc. to have a more refined non-linear trend. However, there are better more advanced ways of handling non-linear effects in regression modeling.